# Firebase Real time database pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add some pagination functionality to my Express + Firebase Realtime Database SDK but I am not sure how to achieve this, and the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data) is not helping me. Also, all the examples I found are regarding Firestore.

Just as an example I have this model **User** which is accessed by `database.ref('users')`. Imagine I have 10 users whose IDs go from 1 to 10 respectively and I want to paginate 5 per page.

What I expect is get users whose keys go from 1 to 5, and then when someone clicks on page 2, it will get users whose keys go from 6 to 10.

According to the documentation, I understood that I should add something like the following:

```js
(req, res) => {
    const { key } = req.query;
    let ref = database.ref('users')
                  .orderByChild('createdAt')
                  .limitToLast(5);
    if (key) { 
        ref = ref.startAt(key);
    }

    ref.once('value')
        .then(snapshot => ...);
}
```

What I get until now is that the difference between `limitToLast()` and `limitToFirst()` is the sorting, it's like `ORDER BY createdAt DESC` and `ORDER BY createdAt ASC` respectively.

If I set `ref.startAt(5)`, the previous code doesn't work since I am getting the first five users (1 to 5).

What approach should I use? Thanks in advance.

#### Edit:

I got that if I do `database.ref('users').orderByChild('createdAt').limitToLast(5).startAt(5)` I get documents where `createdAt` is greater that 5 which is wrong. I should sort by date after getting those documents whose keys are next to 5.

Comment: This [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) describes exactly what you want.

Comment: @Eldar, as mentioned in the question, it shows how to do that with Firestore, I need exactly that for realtime database.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm STRUGGLING lol

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with a very similar scenario, although in reverse -  I wanted to display the last 10 records, and then paginate to the beginning of the list (in my case the list was ordered by date, and I wanted to display the latest dates first);

For your example however, I was able to paginate from 1-5, then 6-10 by implementing the following:

First 5 Users:

```js
database
  .ref('users')
  .orderByChild('createdAt')
  .limitToFirst(6) //Note here that the request is for the first 6 results
  .once("value")
  .then((snap) => {
    const firstSix = snap.val();
    const sixth = firstSix[5].createdAt; //assuming your data is an array, get the last entry


    const startAtNext =  sixth, //this is the 6th value used for pulling the next 5 results - this should be stored globally
    const currentUserList = firstSix.slice(0, firstSix.length -1), //the list of users 1-5
});
```

And for the next 5 users:

```js
database
  .ref('users')
  .orderByChild('createdAt')
  .startAt(startAtNext) // Globally stored variable from first call
  .limitToFirst(6) //Note here that the request is for the first 6 results
  .once("value")
  .then((snap) => {
    const nextSix = snap.val();
    const sixth = nextSix[5].createdAt; //assuming your data is an array, get the last entry


    const startAtNext =  sixth, // the start index for the next request
    const currentUserList = firstSix.slice(0, firstJobsList.length -1), //the next 5 users
});
```

Comment: Any idea why I keep getting this when I try it `Error: Query: When ordering by key, the argument passed to start At(), start After(), endAt(), end Before(), or equal To() must be a string.` ?

Comment: This would likely be due to the data that is being ordered, if the data is stored as type string, i.e. orderByChild is a parameter like 'firstname' then you would have to pass the value of StartAt etc. as a string